# When was the first instance of Generals Morand, Friant & Gudin being referred to as "The Immortals"?

Tags: napoleonic-wars, french-empire

Generals de Division [Morand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Antoine_Morand), [Friant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Friant), and [Gudin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles-%C3%89tienne_Gudin_de_La_Sablonni%C3%A8re) were at times referred to as "The Immortals", as noted in the thesis [*Marshal Louis N. Davout and the Art of Command*](http://ee.valka.cz/doc/pdf/63.pdf) by Major John M. Keefe (1994)(pp36, **my emphasis**)

> Davout's command consisted of the divisions of the **three "immortals", Gudin, Friant, and Morand**, an additional division under St Hilaire, two heavy cavalry divisions under St Sulpice and Montbrun, and one light cavalry division under Jacquinot  (see Appendix B, Order of Battle). This amounted to 67,000 men. **The divisions of Gudin, Morand, and Friant came to be known as Davout's immortals.** They had been together since the Camp of Bruges in 1804 and shared victory with Davout at Austerlitz and Auerstaedt. **They were considered "immortal" in the belief that they could not be defeated.**

I am wondering when, and by whom, this sobriquet was first used in reference to these three accomplished commanders.

### Update #1

- As per a suggestion by [sempaiscuba](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/24858/sempaiscuba) I have checked [**Memoirs of Napoleon** by *Louis Antoine Fauvelet de Bourrienne*](http://www.freeinfosociety.com/media/pdf/4335.pdf) and only found three relevant usages of "**immortal**", none referring to Davout's subordinates:

  > At that time, when he saw his glory and power augmenting, he said to me in one of our walks at Malmaison, in a moment of hilarity, and clapping me on the shoulder, "Well, Bourrienne, you also will be **immortal**!"−− "Why, General?"−−"Are you not my secretary?"−−"Tell me the name of Alexander's," said I.
  >
  > −−[Bonaparte did not know the name of Alexander's secretary, and I forgot at the moment to tell him it was Clallisthenes (sic). He wrote Alexander's Memoirs, as I am writing Bonaparte's; but, notwithstanding this coincidence, I neither expect nor desire the **immortality** of my name.−−Bourrienne.]−−  (pp 241)

  and

  > .. and to Ney, the hero, rather than the Prince of the Moskowa, whose name will be **immortal** in the annals of glory, as his death will be eternal in the annals of party revenge. (pp 485)

  and

  > The conduct of Marmont on that day alone would suffice to **immortalise** him. The corps he commanded was reduced to between 7000 and 8000 infantry and 800 cavalry, with whom, for the space of twelve hours he maintained his ground against an army of 55,000 men, of whom it is said 14,000 were killed, wounded, and taken. Marshal Marmont put himself so forward in the heat of the battle that a dozen of men were killed by the bayonet at his side, and his hat was perforated by a ball. But what was to be done against overwhelming numbers! (pp 515)

### Update #2

- I have found two contradictory accounts. placing the date of the distinction before and after Auerstadt:

  > All that day Davout, with his three famous Divisional-Commanders, already known as the *Three Immortals*, Gudin, Friant and Morand, held out near the village of Auerstadt, ...
  >   from [**Napoleon and his Marshals**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_lc0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT74&dq=three%20immortals%20friant&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja5JmPjP_bAhUeo4MKHZktCB8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=three%20immortals%20friant&f=false)
  >
  > Friant made all the major campaigns with III Corps through 1809, being known as one of the '*three immortals*; (along with Gudin and Morand) after Auerstadt in 1806.
  >   from [**Once There Were Titans: Napoleon's Generals and Their Battles, 1800-1815**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=MxdhDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=three%20immortals%20friant&source=bl&ots=hHGbHahTIN&sig=pSyVg99OTAZIlbPU945wRT6WFjg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFvImxjP_bAhUK5oMKHemxC7YQ6AEIaTAN#v=onepage&q=three%20immortals%20friant&f=false)

Comment: From memory, I think the term was used from the Battle of Jena–Auerstedt (in October 1806) onwards, but I don't have a source at the moment.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Conceptually that makes sense - but with Davout being seriously disliked, if not hated or despised, by virtually all his peers, I am wondering who at that time might have coined the sobriquet. The other likely occassions, of course, are after either Teugn-Hausen or Eggmuhl in April 1809. Those victories were almost as impressive as Auerstadt.

Comment: That I don't know. Mind you, it wouldn't surprise me to find that the term was coined by Napoleon himself. Along the lines of: "My armies cannot be defeated, they are immortals ...".

Comment: I keep wondering if this question looks at the problem the right way. How many people were actually called immortals? My guess is: quite a few more. After Lodi he was called that, after Ulm he called all his soldiers that way. Uffindell 2007 has a book about the whole imperial guard called that way. Is this group really that special in this regard?